# Linking CxxTest in CMake, it says it succeeds but fails to build

Tags: c++, cmake, cxxtest

I just downloaded version 4.4 of cxxtest and unpacked my zip file into this path: C:/cxxtest-4.4. 
Now immediately after, without doing any additional step I opened CLion and tried to add CxxTest to my project as it follows:

```
set(CXXTEST_PYTHON_TESTGEN_EXECUTABLE C:/cxxtest-4.4/python/cxxtest/cxxtestgen.py)
find_package(CxxTest REQUIRED)

if(CXXTEST_FOUND)
    set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Calculator.h TestCalculator.h Calculator.cpp     TestCalculator.h)
    add_executable(Calculator ${SOURCE_FILES})
endif()
```

I had to manually set the two variables cause if I don't i get the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles"     C:\Users\Admin\CLionProjects\Calculator
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find CxxTest (missing: CXXTEST_PYTHON_TESTGEN_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-    3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-    3.7/Modules/FindCxxTest.cmake:221 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Admin/CLionProjects/Calculator/cmake-build-    debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Now everything apparently works fine, and this is my Cmake debug:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -    DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles"     C:\Users\Admin\CLionProjects\Calculator
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to:     C:/Users/Admin/CLionProjects/Calculator/cmake-build-debug
```

When now I try to use cxxtest/TestSuite.h inside an header file, it says it cannot find it. This is driving me crazy, please, I need your help!

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: I managed to link it and now I can find the header files, adding to CMake file this line:

```
include_directories(C:/cxxtest-4.4)
```

Now when I build I get the following output:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --    build C:\Users\Admin\CLionProjects\Calculator\cmake-build-debug --target     Calculator -- -j 8
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable Calculator.exe
CMakeFiles\Calculator.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `  ZN7CxxTest7trackerEv':
C:/cxxtest-4.4/cxxtest/TestTracker.h:130: undefined reference to     `CxxTest::TestTracker::tracker()'
CMakeFiles\Calculator.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function     `ZN7CxxTest14numberToStringIlEEPcT_S1_S2_jj':
C:/cxxtest-4.4/cxxtest/ValueTraits.h:183: undefined reference to     `CxxTest::digitToChar(unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles\Calculator.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZN7CxxTest14doAssertEqualsIiiEEvPKciS2_T_S2_T0_S2_':
C:/cxxtest-4.4/cxxtest/TestSuite.h:146: undefined reference to `CxxTest::doAbortTest()'
CMakeFiles\Calculator.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV14TestCalculator[__ZTV14TestCalculator]+0x14): undefined reference     to `CxxTest::TestSuite::tearDown()'
CMakeFiles\Calculator.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZN14TestCalculatorD1Ev':
C:/Users/Admin/CLionProjects/Calculator/TestCalculator.h:8: undefined     reference to `CxxTest::TestSuite::~TestSuite()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\Calculator.dir\build.make:123: recipe for target 'Calculator.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Calculator.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Calculator.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [Calculator.exe] Error 1
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'Calculator' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Calculator.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Calculator.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Calculator] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is sill a problem, look at the CMake documentation [CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCxxTest.html) documentation for CxxTest.

From your example CMakeLists file it seems you did a cut and past of your normal project files. You must not include the main.cpp file CxxTest generates a file called runner.cpp based on your test deffinition file(s).

So your CxxTest section in the CMakeFiles.txt should look something like this:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/cxxtest/bin)
find_package(CxxTest REQUIRED)
if(CXXTEST_FOUND)
  include_directories(${CXXTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})
  enable_testing()
  CXXTEST_ADD_TEST(tests
      runner.cpp  # THIS IS GENERATED BUT YOU NEED TO ADD IT HERE
      c:/libraries/boost_1_63_0/boost/filesystem.hpp  # THIS SHOULD NOT BE HARD CODED
      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/source/string_tokenizer.cpp  # YOUR PROJECT FILES THAT WILL BE USED FOR YOUR TEST
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/test_stringtokenizer.h  # YOUR TEST DESCRIPTION FILE
  )
  target_link_libraries(tests ${Boost_LIBRARIES})  # LINK BOOST / OTHER THIRD PARTY LIBS TO YOUR TEST
 endif()
```

Hope this helps.